# sharepoint 2007 - how to change the css formting of webpart titles?

Tags: sharepoint

how can i control the CSS of the tiles of web parts in sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 1):

Heather solomon provides great sharepoint branding articles. This describes your questions http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/207.aspx